# I'm a beginner and I'm currently coding a MemoryApp with JQuery

Tags: jquery

The first pass works fine. But at the end there is a button again. And after that it doesn't work anymore. the clicked cards turn around but if there are 2 cards of the same size they are not invisible. Where is the mistake?

```js
let container = document.querySelector("#playField")
let button;
let counter = 0;
let whatClicked = [];
let buttonList = [];
let gamestate = [];
let game1 = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, ];

level1();

function level1() {
  $("#ready").css({
    display: "none"
  })
  counter = 0;
  game1.sort((a, b) => 0.5 - Math.random());

  for (let i = 0; i < game1.length; i++) {
    button = document.createElement('button');
    button.id = "button" + i;
    button.innerHTML = game1[i];
    button.classList.add("buttons")
    container.appendChild(button)

  }
  $("button").click(function() {
    counter++;
    $(this).addClass("buttonsstyle1")
    setTimeout(() => {
      $(this).removeClass("buttonsstyle1")
      $(this).addClass("buttonsstyle2")
    }, 500);
    whatClicked.push($(this).text())
    buttonList.push(($(this).attr('id')))
    $(this).prop("disabled", true);
    if (counter >= 2) {
      $("button").prop("disabled", true);
      if (whatClicked[0] == whatClicked[1]) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          richtig();
        }, 1200);
      } else {
        falsch();
      }
    }
  })
}

function richtig() {
  counter = 0;
  $("#" + buttonList[0]).css({
    opacity: "0"
  }).prop("disabled", true);;
  $("#" + buttonList[1]).css({
    opacity: "0"
  }).prop("disabled", true);;
  gamestate.push(buttonList[0])
  gamestate.push(buttonList[1])
  whatClicked = [];
  buttonList = [];
  $("button").prop("disabled", false);
  fertig();
}

function falsch() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    counter = 0;
    $("#" + buttonList[0]).removeClass("buttonsstyle2");
    $("#" + buttonList[1]).removeClass("buttonsstyle2");

    buttonList = [];
    $("button").prop("disabled", false);
  }, 1200);
}

function fertig() {
  if (gamestate.length == game1.length) {
    $("#ready").css({
      display: "block"
    })
  }
}
$("#again").click(function() {
  gamestate = [];
  $("button").css({
    display: "none"
  });
  level1();
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#head {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20vh;
}

#playField {
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
  height: 80vh;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.buttons {
  background-image: url("logoweiss.svg");
  background-size: 60px 45px;
  background-color: #ac0080;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 36px;
}

.buttonsstyle1 {
  background-image: url();
  background-size: 60px 45px;
  background-color: #1260d4;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 36px;
  animation: toggle 0.5s 1;
}

.buttonsstyle2 {
  background-image: url();
  background-size: 60px 45px;
  background-color: #1260d4;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #fff;
}

@keyframes toggle {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0deg)
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(180deg)
  }
}

#ready {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

#again {
  width: 50%;
  height: 10%;
  font-size: 40px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 3px solid green;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ready">
  <h1>Ready</h1>
  <button id="again">Again</button>
</div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="head">
    <p id="p"></p>
  </div>
  <div id="playField">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"Write a title that **summarizes the specific problem**"_

Comment: I would think you should use more jQuery and delegate: `for (let i = 0; i < game1.length; i++) { $button = $('<button/>',{id:"button" + i}).addClass("buttons").text(game1[i]);$container.append($button)}  $container.on("click","button", function() {`

Comment: You are missing a `container.empty()` before level1()

Comment: Also missing `whatclicked = []` when you get one wrong.  Without this if you get the first pair wrong, every click after checks the first pair and it's always wrong.

Comment: By not adding `$(container).empty()` you're duplicating IDs,  so on round 2nd you have 2x `id=button0` etc, so when you do `$("#" + buttonList[0])` it gets the first one (hidden from round 1) and "unflips" that one instead of the real button[0].

Comment: Also, having a variable "container = $("#playField")` and then an element with `id=container" is just confusing.  As is mixing JS/DOM code with jquery - some of your variables (container) are DOM nodes, while others are jquery.

Comment: There's other issues such as always using `$("button")` which affects *all* the buttons on your page instead of `$("button", container)` or `$(container).find("button")` ... or  `$(".buttons")` would be easier.  And change `container = doc.query("#playField")` to `var playField = $("#playField")` as it will save you headaches.

Comment: thank you for your information. there is still a lot to learn. so the code in the 2nd round now works better. only with the first click in round 2 is the name of the again button in the whatClicked array in the first position. the first pair does not go away. then it works because the name of the button was then deleted from the array. but why does it include it again in the array?